# Error running multiple commands using here document in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ssh, sed

I'm trying to execute the following set of commands in 3 remote servers using arrays, using Here Document, but getting an error

**code -**

```
ssh -oPasswordAuthentication=no $remoteUser@${SERVER[i]} <<-END_TEXT
VALUE=`cat /home/cognos/cognos/c8/configuration/cogstartup.xml | grep -i xsd:long | head -1 | cut -d">" -f2 | sed 's/[:/<|crn:value]*//g'`
VALUE_BACKUP=$VALUE
........................ (many more lines of code)
RESULT1=`perl -e '@stats = stat("/home/cognos/cognos/c8/configuration/signkeypair"); print ((time - $stats[9]) < '$VALUE');'`

END_TEXT
```

And the error:

```
**error -**
syntax error at -e line 1, near "< )"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
syntax error at -e line 1, near "< )"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
syntax error at -e line 1, near "< )"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

ps- using scp to copy commands to remote server and then running them using ssh is not a solution I'm looking for.

Comment: Hint: use `cat - <<-END_TEXT ... ` to find out how the variable substitution works within the here document.

Comment: There is very likely a syntax error buried somewhere in `(many more lines of code)`

Comment: I've added the perl command which uses -e, also there is no syntax error in (many more lines of code) as it runs properly locally i.e when I don't use ssh.

Comment: Are you intending to run the `cat` and `perl` commands on the local machine, where the ssh client lives, or should those commands be executed on the remote server? Have you thought about perhaps putting this stuff into a script, that takes command line options, instead of evaluating variable assignments in a heredoc?  This is very scary code. If I saw it on a server I was responsible for, I would disable whatever functionality it was responsible for until the whole process could be refactored.

Comment: @ghoti I am intending to run the `cat` and `perl` commands on the remote server. These commands are already a part of a script. If u want, I can add the entire heredoc ?

Comment: Unless you escape your backticks, the commands in the heredoc will be run on the local machine, not remote.  As I suggested, you should refactor this.\

Answer (score 2):

Look into the whole here document and search for `-e`.

**Edit:**

Enclose END_TEXT in single quotes, like this:

```
ssh ... <<-'END_TEXT'
...
END_TEXT
```

This will prevent substitution of $VALUE with an empty string, before it is available on the remote server.

Comment: The `-` merely removes indentation from the heredoc and is not likely to be the source of the problem.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Ok, I didn't know this variation.

Comment: @OlafDietsche I've added the perl -e command. It runs fine when not using ssh